# Strategy for abstracting rendering from draw surface

Tags: architecture, design-patterns, rendertargets

This question might be a little vague because I don't know how to do this myself and I might be asking something rather silly. So here we go.

Up to now, when I did my personal graphics code I used OpenGL and something like SDL to get the context to draw. And my projects were rather small and educational. Now I want to structure things a little bit. Rather than having an OpenGL engine, I want to have an abstract renderer. Let's say I have something like;

```
/* Beware of possibly non-sense pseudocode */ 
class Renderer<typename DrawSurface>
{
    public:
    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void update();
    ...
    virtual void render();
    private:
    DrawSurface mDrawContext;
}
```

You could guess that this `DrawSurface` will represent where we draw. For example, this might be an image, a framebuffer, an OpenGL context from SDL etc. There could be an interface here and I am planning to implement this for needed drawing options. For now, I am planning to have a software renderer and a Qt OpenGL widget. Then, maybe I can do as follows in my initialize method:

```
void Renderer::initialize()
{
    mDrawSurface.setUpDrawContext();
    // ... other things
}
```

and this should set up an OpenGL context if DrawSurface implements it in that way. What I want to finally achieve is the ability to get different versions of my graphics program easily. Let's say I am using `Renderer<QtOpenGLContext>` in my editor. I am using a Qt widget to render and I am using other widgets from Qt for my editor's UI. My editor might have a tool button called `Assemble` and when I click on this I want a version with SDL context to be generated and compiled so that resulting graphics program will not depend on Qt, only the tools. The main part might look like this:

```
int main(argc, argv)
{
    Scene<OpenGLRenderer> scene;
    while(inGameLoop)
    {
        ...
        scene.updateScene(); // handle edit events
        scene.renderScene();
        ...
    }
}
```

Assemble will take this scene and convert it to have type `Scene<OpenGLRenderer>` and compile using that. So a need to serializing scenes, maybe, might also come into play here.

You can see that I am confused :). I am looking for strategies on how to achieve this. How we can encode this better on type system so that, for example, an OpenGL renderer won't try to render to an image but it will require an OpenGL context at compile time? How can we make it also work with physically-based rendering? This might require a rather long answer I reckon, so pointing to other resources like books, articles etc. is also fine.